# clickevent in javascript

Tags: javascript

what is difference between onclick and onclientclick events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `onclientclick` does not exist in Javascript.

It's an ASP.net extension. As shown in the example in MSDN's [Button.OnClientClick Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) page, `onclientclick` will call client-side script, while `onclick` will call the server-side script.